# View becomes invisible when I add attach custom view background to the view

Tags: android-custom-view, android-drawable, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to add a custom background to a button to make two sides rounded. But when I attach or add custom view background, the button becomes invisible. Here is my xml code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
Have Some Code there 

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Top"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

    android:drawableTop="@drawable/baseline_remove_24"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:translationZ="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mid_button"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_mid"
    android:text="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Top" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bottom_side"
    //background added there
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/baseline_add_24"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:translationZ="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code for custom view from drawable folder is here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="50dp" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    padding android:left="20dp" android:top="20dp"
    android:right="20dp" android:bottom="20dp" />
   </shape>
```

Image is below:
[image]
(https://imghostr.com/BwBwqrc1)